# Create a dummy variable from if any value from multiple column is over a certain value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dummy-variable

I want to create a new dummy variable if the any of the three colunm exceeds a certain value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'amount_1':[1,8,9,1,10,12],'amount_2':[2,9,6,5,2,1],'amount_3':[2,5,1,5,5,7]})
print(df)
```

I want a dummy variable if any value in colunm amount_1, amount_2 or amount_3 is  greater than 5

```
df = {'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'amount_1':[1,2,1,1,10,2],amount_2:[2,9,6,5,2,1],'amount_3':[2,5,1,5,5,3],'dummy':[0,1,1,0,1,0]}
print(df)
```

Comment: `df['dummy'] = (df.filter(like='amount') > 5).any(axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: Not an exact dupe of the link but this has been asked before.

Comment: @cs95 can you care to elaborate more about your code. I don't really know what  the like='amount' does.